# json succes message shawn

Tags: php, jquery

I try to confirm that an email was sent with JSON and then cath the event with ajax and display a succes message on the screen.
The problem is that the email is not sent, and I get redirected to the "sended":true because of the first part of the php script. The html and css is ok, I have tested it a lot.
What I actually want is to send the email with php and than use ajax to display a succes or error message. The problem is that I this is the first time that I use php and I just can't find the correct way. I would not ask this, but I have to deliver the project by tonight and this is the last thing to be done.
You can check it in action at: http://webofdreams.ro/vworker/finemaid/finemaid.html# under email us link.

JS:

```
$ajax({
                     "type":"POST",
                     "url":"sendemail1.php",
                     "data": { name1: name1Val, emailFrom1: emailFrom1Val, comments: commentsVal},
                     "dataType":'json',
                     "success":function(response){
                         if (response.sended){
                            alert ("Mail Sended ok"); //Code after mail send
                           }else{
                            alert (response.error); //Code or allert on error
                           }
                          },                
                     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                      alert(xhr.status+" "+thrownError);
                     }
```

php:

```
$send = @mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom1); 
if ($send){
    echo mail($mailTo, $subject, $message, "From: ".$mailFrom1) ? '{"sended":true}':'{"sended":false,"error":"Mail send fail."}';
}else{
 echo '{"sended":false,"error":"Request Error."}';
};
```

Comment: are you having problem sending email or just shown success message with ajax is the only problem

Comment: @viktor you do realize that this script will send two emails, don't you ?

Comment: actually it's $.ajax not $ajax, install firebug for firefox it will show you the error you have in jquery code...

Comment: I know it will send 2 emails, this is for testing purposes, as it is now it send one email with the first mail() function and the second throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax request is full of errors so i have wrote it from scratch, the below script will atleast take care of the ajax request.

```
        $(function(){
        name1Val = 'CaptureName';
        emailFrom1Val = 'CaptureEmail';
        commentsVal = 'CaptureComments';
        parameters = 'name1=' + name1Val + '&emailFrom1=' + emailFrom1Val + '&comments=' + commentsVal;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmail.php",
            data: parameters,
            error: function(response){
                alert(response);
            },
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Aside from defining the variables I do not see major differences. The problem is almost sure in the php code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I spot an error in your code

```
$.ajax({
 ^                    "type":"POST",
 |                    "url":"sendemail1.php",
 |                    "data": { name1: name1Val, emailFrom1: emailFrom1Val, comments: commentsVal},
                     "dataType":'json',
                     "success":function(response){
                         if (response.sended){
                            alert ("Mail Sended ok"); //Code after mail send
                           }else{
                            alert (response.error); //Code or allert on error
                           }
                          },   

         ----------->error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                      alert(xhr.status+" "+thrownError);
                    // should be 
         ----------->"error": function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                      alert(xhr.status+" "+thrownError);

                     }
```

Comment: michael also it needs to be $.ajax